# How to change ContentView when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, setcontentview

**Hey guys,**
I need help with changing a ContentView in the MainActivity (without changing the Activity).
I want to display "Special Thanks". In there are names of users who helped me localizing and testing the app.
For that, I am using a button with

```
android:onClick="onSpcThxButtonClick"
```

The xml I want to display is called "spcthx.xml"

I need you to complete the following code:

```
public void onSpcThxButtonClick (View view)
{
        // insert ContentView switch here
}
```

Hope you are able to help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.spcthx);

Comment: @dymmeh No. Eclipse says that setContentView doesn't exist (even though it works in onCreate).

Comment: @dymmeh (Unknown method "setContentView")

Answer (score 0):

You can't use setcontentview easily on just calling a setcontentview function. You can use Framelayout to remove all views and inflate new layout to change/switch different views. I hope this will help.

Comment: Hm. Okay. Thank you. If no one knows a different answer, it's easier to call a different activity though.

Comment: or yes, you can call another activity and call setContentView. But your target is to change dynamically when presses a button without losing an activity right?

Comment: Yep. Because I want the user to be able to just press the back key on their phone instead of relaunching MainActivity with a "back" button.

Comment: Oh. I think that was the solution. But if no one suggest that is easier to code, try my suggestion. I will help you. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".Settings" >

<!-- Settings  -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings_form"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Special Thanks -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/special_thanks_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >


</LinearLayout>
```

Then on your Activity just reference them

```
private View            settingsForm;
private View            specialThanksForm;

settingsForm      = findViewById(R.id.settings_form);
specialThanksForm = findViewById(R.id.special_thanks_form);
```

Then change the visibility for the Views on your button clickListener

```
settingsForm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
specialThanksForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I will edit your suggestion a little, though I have two buttons in the main.xml, thank you sooo much!

Comment: Yeah i was just explaining a general situation.. glad it helped